# How to insert a new element into an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, insertion

I have an array arr of size n, and I need to insert a new element new_element at position pos. I'm looking for a solution that is efficient and adheres to best practices in C programming.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us, describing what problems you have with it.

Comment: As for inserting elements into arrays, you can't. An array have a fixed size once its been created.

Comment: But by taking more size of array

Comment: Like I said, once you have defined an array, its size is *fixed*. Do you perhaps mean a *dynamic "array"* as allocated by e.g. `malloc`? Then you need to edit your question and tell us that (together with the aforementioned [mcve]).

Comment: Thanks for you guideline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add elements if your array is big enough and you manage its actual size manually (and make sure it stays below the max allocated size). You just have to copy all the elements above the insertion point to higher locations (based on how many items you want to insert), which is very inefficient. However, unlike linked data structures, you retain the benefits of working with an array that way.

There are data structures that combined the ~best of both worlds (more or less) by managing linked arrays, but they're more complicated to manage.

Comment: Um.. no. Sorry, this is not a coding service and we don't get payed to do your homework for you. I gave you a direction - you can go ahead and try to implement it, and if you have any further question post your code and we can help.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, you can't add any new element in the array, try to use [a linked list](https://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cant add new elements on arrays on C programming. You need to create linked lists for a dynamic list.

After you learn how to build structures, you can start checking out data structures ([What is a Data Structure?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/)) which include Linked lists. Then you can start working on Linked Lists ([What is a Linked List?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/)) so you can build dynamic lists.

Hope this would be helpful